# Adaptive bandwidth allocation?

Tags: networking, network-programming

In our File Transfer application the network performance was fair

but we want to get the maximum network performance so one way of achieving through

adaptive bandwidth allocation .So the application will be forced to attain the

available bandwidth.friends!!! if u have any white papers or code for reference

it would be much helpful :)

thanks

krishna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just throw it at the TCP session with no control, it will transfer at full speed.

You could also compact the file as you transfer. It will not accelerate the transfer, but will optmize the use of the network, at CPU coast.

If it is not enough, the only [software] way to improve that even more is by using multiple TCP sessions so you will reduce the speed delimitating effects of the latency over the TCP flow control. I beleave 5 concurrent transfers from different offsets of the same file will do the job, faster impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "adaptive bandwidth allocation" really means anything tangible (considering it's the #2 google hit for that expression!) but I'll try to give an answer that might help you ask a better question.

If an application's network activity can be parallelised (bittorrent is a good example of this) then this is one way of achieving faster network transfers.

In general though, for user space applications the networking conditions are going to be outside the application's control for good reasons. If a userspace application considers it part of its mandate to adjust or affect external operating system-level networking conditions I would consider it malware. [QoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) for example could be used to prioritise the traffic associated with your application but that is something you might want to suggest and explain in a deployment guide and not try to manage from within your application.